# Sync two location not accessible at same time and machine

Tags: synchronization, data-synchronization

need one solution for one way(Mirror) file sync between two different location on different machine, and cannot accessible at same time.

E.G. one PC(named "Offline-PC") dont have network connection it can be only accessible via pendrive.

would like to sync Multiple file/folders ~300Gb/1M files to other PC (Named "online-PC")

is there any way i can create "Files List" on Online-PC and take the list to Offline-PC
and command software only copy files in pendrive NOT available in "file list" ?? and will take it to online-PC paste it with replace it?

need help for this unique requirement,

tried freesync and other option but not found any,